# log X amount not in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm using Javascript trying to log the same string multiple times. Is there a way to do this without iterating through a loop? When I try it with a loop it logs the string 4 times adding to it each time.

I want to log the string once, but with all four items in it.

For example, I want:

```
0000
```

and not:

```
0
00
000
0000
```

Here's what I've tried:

```js
var string = ''

function zero(x) {
  for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(string += x)
  }
}

zero('0')
```

Is it possible to skip logging the first three outputs and just log `0000` on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have log outside the loop. Also it is good practice to use semi-columns

```
var string = '';

function zero(x) {
    for (i=0; i<=3; i++) {
       string += x;
    }
   console.log(string);
}

zero('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do the same.

```js
function zero(x, n) {
  console.log(x.repeat(n));
}

zero("0", 4);
```